# how to make an search function in react native

Tags: react-native

This is an reference of git hub and using this code to make as same searh function in react native with this example?
      but i want to make a serach function  after user inputs then it should

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, FlatList, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import { ListItem, SearchBar } from 'react-native-elements';

class Search extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      loading: false,
      data: [],
      error: null,
    };

    this.arrayholder = [];
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.makeRemoteRequest();
  }

  makeRemoteRequest = () => {
    const url = `https://www.achhamall.com/staging-achhamall.com/index.php?route=webservices/api&method=appGetCategoryDetails`;
    this.setState({ loading: true });

    fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({
          data: res.products,
          error: res.error || null,
          loading: false,
        });
        this.arrayholder = res.products;
        console.log(res.products)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.setState({ error, loading: false });
      });
  };

  renderSeparator = () => {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          height: 1,
          width: '86%',
          backgroundColor: '#CED0CE',
          marginLeft: '14%',
        }}
      />
    );
  };

  searchFilterFunction = text => {
    this.setState({
      value: text,
    });

    const newData = this.arrayholder.filter(item => {
      const itemData = `${item.name.toUpperCase()} ${item.name.toUpperCase()}`;
      const textData = text.toUpperCase();

      return itemData.indexOf(textData) > -1;
    });
    this.setState({
      data: newData,
    });
  };

  renderHeader = () => {
    return (
      <SearchBar
        placeholder="Type Here..."
        lightTheme
        round
        onChangeText={text => this.searchFilterFunction(text)}
        autoCorrect={false}
        value={this.state.value}
      />
    );
  };

  render() {
    if (this.state.loading) {
      return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
          <ActivityIndicator />
        </View>
      );
    }
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.data}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <ListItem

              title={item.name}
            />
          )}
          keyExtractor={item => item.name}
          ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
          ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default Search;
```

and while running and typing the text to input gives error undefined is not an object (evaluating _'this.arrayholder.filter')

Answer (score 2):

Check out this code snippet , how you can use search and implement it in the Flatlist

```
     import React from 'react';
    import MapView,{ Marker } from 'react-native-maps';
    import {
      SafeAreaView,
      StyleSheet,
      ScrollView,
      View,
      Image,
  Text,
  ToastAndroid,
  PermissionsAndroid,
  StatusBar,
  Platform,

} from 'react-native';
import {Header,SearchBar,ListItem} from 'react-native-elements';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';

import {Fab} from 'native-base';
import { from } from 'rxjs';
const axios = require('axios');


class App extends React.Component{

  state = {
    search: '',
    searchResponse: [],
    isFlatlistVisible: false,

    loading: false
  };





  queryText = (text="") => {

    if(text==""){
      this.setState({searchResponse: []});


    }

    else{
      axios.get(`http:ww.gdhdhdh.com`)
      .then((response) => {

        this.setState({searchResponse: response.data.prop_data});

      });
    }
    }

  updateSearch = search => {

    this.setState({ search });
    this.queryText(search)
  };

  componentDidMount(){
   this.queryText()


  }
  render(){

    const{search} = this.state;
    const {searchResponse} = this.state;

    return(

      <>
      <StatusBar backgroundColor="blue" barStyle="light-content" />


     <SearchBar
       placeholder="Type Here..."
       onChangeText={this.updateSearch}
       value={search}

       />}

     />
    <View>

    </View>
     {this.state.search?<ScrollView>
     {
    searchResponse.map((item, i) => (

      <ListItem
        key={i}
        title={item.name}
        bottomDivider
        onPress= {() => ToastAndroid.show(`${item.name}`, ToastAndroid.SHORT)}
      />

    ))
  }
  </ScrollView>:<View style={styles.container}>

    </View> }


         </>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
     flex:1,
      alignItems: 'center',
    },
    map: {
      height: "100%",
      width: "100%",
    },
  textColor: {
    color: 'white',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 20,
    marginBottom: 15
  },
  red: {
    color: 'red',
  },
});


    export default App;
```

Comment: Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component gives error

Comment: you are rendering text but without wrapping it in the Text component, show the code

Comment: i have set fake api in it use your api and set state accordingly

Comment: lets chat do u have chat option available then join us ?

Comment: i dont think i have chat option, how to do that

Comment: and i have edited the url but still error same and state option value also changed but still the error is same ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208388/discussion-between-wahdat-kashmiri-and-aoudesh01).

Comment: you need to pass search_item in the body of the post call

Answer (score 1):

This happened because your data is not fetching therefor **arrayholder** get undefined  check your **url**. and You can solve this issue using this

```
this.arrayholder = res.products == undefined ? [] :res.products;
```

in **makeRemoteRequest** function

Check below code,

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, FlatList, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import { ListItem, SearchBar } from 'react-native-elements';

class Search extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      loading: false,
      data: [],
      error: null,
    };

    this.arrayholder = [];
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.makeRemoteRequest();
  }

  makeRemoteRequest = () => {
    const url = `https://www.achhamall.com/staging-achhamall.com/index.php?route=webservices/api&method=appGetCategoryDetails`;
    this.setState({ loading: true });

    fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({
          data: res.products,
          error: res.error || null,
          loading: false,
        });
        this.arrayholder = res.products == undefined ? [] :res.products;
        console.log(res.products)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.setState({ error, loading: false });
      });
  };

  renderSeparator = () => {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          height: 1,
          width: '86%',
          backgroundColor: '#CED0CE',
          marginLeft: '14%',
        }}
      />
    );
  };

  searchFilterFunction = text => {
    this.setState({
      value: text,
    });
        console.log('dddd',this.arrayholder)
    const newData = this.arrayholder.filter(item => {
      const itemData = `${item.name.toUpperCase()} ${item.name.toUpperCase()}`;
      const textData = text.toUpperCase();

      return itemData.indexOf(textData) > -1;
    });
    this.setState({
      data: newData,
    });
  };

  renderHeader = () => {
    return (
      <SearchBar
        placeholder="Type Here..."
        lightTheme
        round
        onChangeText={text => this.searchFilterFunction(text)}
        autoCorrect={false}
        value={this.state.value}
      />
    );
  };

  render() {
    if (this.state.loading) {
      return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
          <ActivityIndicator />
        </View>
      );
    }
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.data}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <ListItem

              title={item.name}
            />
          )}
          keyExtractor={item => item.name}
          ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
          ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default Search;
```

Feel free for doubts.

Comment: still not getting the data as its an post request to the url ?